# New and old values in postgresql php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, insert, insert-update

I have a table containing lots of data. In this table I would like to add new and update old values. Therefore, I found the following method

After adapting the query from the response, I still got an error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 
ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 3: ...richia coli',full_name = 
'Escherichia coli' WHERE id = '0' ^ in /var/www/html/Insert.php:127 Stack 
trace: #0 /var/www/html/Insert.php(127): PDO->query('INSERT INTO spe...') #1 
{main} thrown in /var/www/html/Insert.php on line 127
```

The adapted query is :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO species (id,match,full_name)
VALUES ('".$var_id."','".$var_match ."','".$var_full_name."')".
"ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET match = '".$var_match."',full_name = '".$var_full_name."' ". 
" WHERE id = '".$var_id."' ";
```

For some reason it still doesn't seem to recognise ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET. See picture[image]
Could someone tell me were I got it wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found. I split the query into because the ON CONFLICT wasn't working for me. First I use select to determine if row already exist by checking if id is present. If id is present the data is update. If the idea is not present a new row is added.

#### Function

```
function execute_query($query,$dbh){
    if ($dbh->query($query)) {
        return "New Record Inserted Successfully!<br \>\n";
    }else{
        return "Data not successfully Inserted.<br \>\n";
    } 
}
```

#### Select and prepare statement

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM species '. 'WHERE id = '. "'".$var_id."'";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$out = $stmt->fetch();
print_r($out) ;
```

#### If result => update row

```
if ($out !== false){
    $sql = "UPDATE species SET id = '".$var_id."', match ='".$var_match."',full_name = '".$var_full_name."'
    WHERE id = '".$var_id."' ";
    echo $sql ."<br \>\n";;
    execute_query($sql,$dbh); # function
    echo "Value is updated";

}else{ ### If no result => insert new values
    $sql = "INSERT INTO species (id,match,full_name)VALUES 
    ('".$var_id."','".$var_match ."','".$var_full_name."')";
    execute_query($sql,$dbh);
    echo "New value is inserted";
```

Answer (score 1):

`EXCLUDED.'".$var_match."'`will become something like `EXCLUDED.'Escherichia coli'` and `'Escherichia coli'`sure isn't a column.

Either use

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO species (id,match,full_name)
VALUES ('".$var_id."','".$var_match ."','".$var_full_name."')".
"ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET match = '".$var_match."',full_name = '".$var_full_name."' ";
```

or

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO species (id,match,full_name)
VALUES ('".$var_id."','".$var_match ."','".$var_full_name."')".
"ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET match = EXCLUDED.match,full_name = EXCLUDED.full_name ";
```

And you're probably also missing a `WHERE id = '".$var_id."'` or `WHERE id = EXCLUDED.id` for the `UPDATE`.

Comment: When I use the above function I still got an error. Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 3: ...richia coli',full_name = 'Escherichia coli' WHERE id = '0' ^ in /var/www/html//Insert.php:127 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html//Insert.php(127): PDO->query('INSERT INTO spe...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Inser.php on line 127

Comment: @Nemo: Try to qualify `id`. `species.id` or `excluded.id`, whichever you actually mean (I guess `species.id`?).

Comment: @Nemo? The values might be. But that's another story. Here the DBMS doesn't know if you meant `species.id` or `excluded.id`, both are possible for `id`. That's why you need to qualify it, so that the DBMS knows which one you meant.

Comment: I tried it but it still wasn't working. So I split the query into in stead of using the on conflict.